# convert nested dict values in pyspark/pandas dataframe to column and rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with only one record.  it contains an id field and a "value" field.  the value field contains nested dicts like the example record shown in the inputdf below.  I would like to create a new dataframe like the outputdf below, where the type column is the keys from the nested dict in the value field in inputdf, and the value and active columns contain corresponding values from the nested dicts.  if it's easier, the dataframe could be converted to a pandas dataframe using .toPandas().  does anyone have a slick way to do this?

inputdf:

```
id value
1  {"soda":{"value":2,"active":1},"jet":{"value":0,"active":1}}
```

outputdf:

```
type  value active
soda  2     1
jet   0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try , notice here I also include the id column

```
yourdf = pd.DataFrame(df.value.tolist(),index=df.id).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
Out[13]: 
   id level_1  value  active
0   1    soda      2       1
1   1     jet      0       1
```